# Initiating TCP Client after running reactor.run()

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to make a p2p app for sending just text messages. The way I am doing it is by having a server that keeps running as long as the application is running, and a client that connects to other node's server to send messages.
For testing purposes I am doing it with localhost, i.e. talking to myself.

So i have following:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from mylib import MessageSFactory

def send_message(message):
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8080, MessageCFactory(message))

reactor.listenTCP(8080, MessageSFactory())
reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8080, MessageCFactory("this message gets received"))
reactor.run()

send_message("this message doesn't")
```

However the problem is calling `send_message` (last line) after `reactor.run` seems to have no effect.

The problem is I need to run the tcp client part (`connectTCP`) only when the user fills in a message, and sends it. So I am trying to do that with calling `send_message`. So how can I fix the above code to make that work?

From what I have read so far, using `LoopingCall` would be the way to go, but than I have to store new messages the client inputs into a variable, and constantly check that variable for a new message and than run `send_message` This would result in a delay between the user input and the function callback, regardless is this my best option?

Is there some other way to do it in this scenario? Or am I lacking understanding of some crucial part of *twisted*'s architecture?

EDIT: As requested, here's the GUI code, that takes the message input from the client:

```
from Tkinter import *

def send_message():
   print("message: %s" % (e1.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Message").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(master, text='Send', command=send_message).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
mainloop()
```

Thanks

Comment: how does "messages the client inputs" work?  What causes that to happen?  Can you show that code?

Comment: done... added the user input part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial problem is that both Tkinter and Twisted solve similar problems in similar ways, namely, reacting asyncronously to external events.  The fact that Tkinter is focused on *gui* events and Twitsted on *network* events is of only passing importance.

The specific thing they do is that they have a "main loop" structure, a sort of point of no return from which you lose control.  In the case of twisted, that's usually `reactor.run()`, and in tkinter, that'll be `Tkinter.mainloop()`.  Both will not return until the program exits.

Fortunately, you can get Twisted to [manage tk's event loop for you!](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#auto16)  At the begining of your program, you should add:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from twisted.internet import tksupport
root_window = Tk()
tksupport.install(root_window)
```

then, Once you've created your gui as normal, you should *not* call `Tkinter.mainloop()`, use:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
root_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

The odd bit with `Tk.protocol()` is optional, but will get rid of some gruesome exceptions by shutting the reactor normally when the gui tries to exit.

---

In case that's not quite enough, here's some real, working code!  First a really simple server

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'recieved:', data
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'connection closed', reason

f = Factory()
f.protocol = Echo
reactor.listenTCP(8080, f)
reactor.run()
```

and a client, with a gui and network activity:

```
from Tkinter import *
from twisted.internet import tksupport, reactor
master = Tk()
tksupport.install(master)

def send_message():
    message = e1.get()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8080, MessageCFactory(message))
    print("message: %s" % (message))

Label(master, text="Message").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(master, text='Send', command=send_message).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MessageCProto(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.message)
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class MessageCFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MessageCProto

    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```